# How do I get a different result with the same state call in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, random, jsx

My apologies for the confusing wording of the question. Basically when I call state from here:

```
    this.state = {
     newdiscoverPlanet: [
      'sunp',
      'twop',
      'bluep',
      'purplep',
      'bluepurplep',
      'redp',
      'orangep'

    ],
};

_getRandomPlanet(){
  var planetItem = this.state.newdiscoverPlanet[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.newdiscoverPlanet.length)];
  this.setState({
    currentPlanet: planetItem,
  });
}
```

How do I get a different result from the same state?

```
<Text>{this.state.currentPlanet}</Text>
<Text>{this.state.currentPlanet}</Text>
<Text>{this.state.currentPlanet}</Text>
```

I know I could just add two more different states with all the items of `newdiscoverPlanet` but 1) I have a chance of getting the same results 2) It seems too lengthy for something that might have an easier solution.

Comment: Can you post your full state object? Your current state doesn't have `currentPlanet` `property.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the randomly generated name in the state, but instead, call the function to generate a random name multiple times in your `render` function.

Basically something like that should do the trick:

```
_getRandomPlanet(){
  var planetItem = this.state.newdiscoverPlanet[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.newdiscoverPlanet.length)];
  return planetItem
}
```

And in your JSX:

```
<Text>{this._getRandomPlanet()}</Text>
<Text>{this._getRandomPlanet()}</Text>
<Text>{this._getRandomPlanet()}</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am having a hard time getting this into this: `require("../img/" + this._getRandomPlanet() + ".png")`. Is there a way I can put a function in `require` like this?

Comment: I think you can consider importing all the planet images and then pick the one you want according to the randomly generated name.

Comment: I think you should put the randomly generated name in the state because otherwise you won't be able to control when the set of planet is randomized and each time the parent render the set of planet will change.

Comment: Agree. If it's important to keep the randomly generated values, then you should consider remix23's solution

Comment: @LaneyWilliams You cannot dynamically require in react-native.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if `newdiscoverPlanet` is constant it shouldn't be in the state (a file constant, or static member, an instance or even a prop member would do but it's not really a state of the component).

Then from what I understand of your questions it seems that you want a random selection of `newDiscoverPlanet` instead of just one.

And from what I read from a comment it also seems that you need to import image files for each planet.

So what about:

```
    import sunpImg from '../img/sunp.png';
    import twopImg from '../img/twop.png';
    import bluepImg from '../img/bluep.png';
    import purplepImg from '../img/purplep.png';
    import bluepurplepImg from '../img/bluepurplep.png';
    import redpImg from '../img/redp.png';
    import orangepImg from '../img/orangep.png';

    const planetsObj = [
        { name:'sunp', img: sunpImg },
        { name:'twop', img: twopImg },
        { name:'bluep', img: bluepImg },
        { name:'purplep', img: purplepImg },
        { name:'bluepurplep', img: bluepurplepImg },
        { name:'redp', img: redpImg },
        { name:'orangep', img: orangepImg },
    ];

    class YouComponent extends Component {

        state = {
            randomPlanets: this.getRandomPlanets()
        }
        getRandomPlanets() {
            // Note: since the randomization relies on random sorting
            // you won't have the same planet twice, if you want a 
            // subset (less planets) just use .slice(numOfItem)
            return [...planetsObj].sort(() => parseInt(Math.random() * 3, 10) - 1);
        }
        updateRandomPlanets() {
            this.setState(() => ({ randomPlanets: this.getRandomPlanets() }));
        }
        render() {
            const { randomPlanets } = this.state;
            // Note: if you randomize during render the renders
            // won't be consistent and the display won't be controllable
            return (
                {randomPlanets.map(planet => (
                    <div>
                        <img src={planet.img} />
                        <Text>{planet.name}</Text>
                    </div>
                ))}
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot dynamically require values in react-native. So this solution won't work

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, today I've learned. I've also updated the answer with static imports. The imports could also be pre built or maybe a dynamic import solution exists for react native, but it's another story...